# JDBI erro No mapper registered for type

Tags: java, jdbi, jdbi3, jdbi3-core

I'm trying to create a method that return all users from customer table in my database but this code:

```
    try {
        List<Customer> customer = jdbi.open().createQuery("SELECT * FROM customer")
        .mapTo(Customer.class).list();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

return error:

```
org.jdbi.v3.core.mapper.NoSuchMapperException: No mapper registered for type com.customer.Customer
```

i saw another post of this error and they say that this error happened because of the mapping between the class model and the database table, but my app is built in pure java and JDBI 3 I'm not using Spring so how map the result of this code for convert this result in a List of Customer?

Comment: Why don't you stick to the [offical docs](https://jdbi.org/#_fluent_api)?

Comment: I understood your answer and read it several times, it doesn't show how to implement my question on a specific mapping like this, and the examples there are not clear, especially for someone starting out, but anyway, I'm testing a lot of things that I see there, if I solve this issue alone, I'll answer this post to help other people, anyway, thanks for your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fix this creating this class

```
public class CustomerMapper implements RowMapper<Customer>{

  @Override
  public Customer map(ResultSet rs, StatementContext ctx) throws SQLException {
    return new Customer(rs.getInt("id"), rs.getString("uuid"), rs.getString("name"), rs.getString("email"), rs.getString("birthDate"), rs.getString("cpf"), rs.getString("gender"), rs.getDate("createdAt"), rs.getDate("updateAt"));
  }
}
```

and where was `.mapTo(Customer.class).list();` i put `.map(new CustomerMapper()).list();` referencing the map I created

Comment: I am not sure what `Customer` is, but from the code above and usage of all-args constructor I am confident that you could not write your own mapper but simply use [ConstructorMapper](http://jdbi.org/#_constructormapper): `registerRowMapper(ConstructorMapper.factory(Customer.class))`

Comment: @YuriiMelnychuk thank you so much, i modified my code and now it ran very well and so fast, you are amazing <3

Answer (score 0):

For me this usually happens when running tests with IntelliJ. Everything works fine when running the same tests with Maven.